# CSS Animations not working (previously worked)

Tags: html, css, animation

These animations were previously working but my CSS was really messy so I cleaned it up and they stopped working after that. **The part you should be looking at is the .pbc and .ft and the shake and rightThenLeft keyframes.**

Here is my CSS:
http://pbear.comli.com/main.css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/I3ANNED/g56bgfap/1/

```
<footer>
<h6 align="right" class="ft"><strong>http://youtube.com/zturbin</strong></p>
</footer>
<div class="pbc"><h5 class="pbct" align="center" style="font-family:Impact;
font-size: 3em; line-height:1.6em;">PB</p></div>
```

*The animation works when it is alone but not with the rest of the site.*

**The last animation starts after you are on the site for 70 seconds.**

Comment: make a fiddle of specific code

Comment: also state the expected behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And after that, include the relevant parts of the code in the question. Linking to an external source will make this question useless immediately after the link goes down.

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/I3ANNED/g56bgfap/1/

I want the div to shake and the text to go left to right, it works in the fiddle but the css I linked to in the main post has the the exact same code but doesn't work. (It use to work.)

Comment: Please don't add more and more jsfiddle links in comments. Update your question with a minimal, complete example in a code snippet that you can find in the question editor.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my old comment. Anyway, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket in your rainbow keyframes for webkit in main.css. This is causing a CSS parsing error that's keeping your animations from running.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {

  0%{background-position:0% 82%}
  50%{background-position:100% 19% /* <----- Missing closing bracket */
  100%{background-position:0% 82%}

}
```

Corrected CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {

  0%{background-position:0% 82%}
  50%{background-position:100% 19%}
  100%{background-position:0% 82%}

}
```

Comment: And now I can't get that song out of my head.